# Raspbian Linux 4.1 dma_map_sg(): Populate .page_link?

Tags: c, linux, driver, raspbian, dma

I need to setup for the dma_map_sg() call in a Raspbian Linux 4.1 character mode driver. From what I've been able to determine the entries that need to be setup in the sg_list[] are:

```
.page_link
.offset                   
.length
```

The problem I am having is with the .page_link member. What I have are some user mode virtual memory pointers. Since this is a dma engine interface, I presume a kernel virtual address is needed here. The issue is how to populate the .page_link?

The user mode virtual addresses are memory mapped regions from the GPU (to be safe from CPU cache). These are setup in the user mode program, and passed into the char driver using ioctl(2).

This is for the Raspberry Pi 2, the goal being to DMA capture GPIO bits into blocks of memory for capture (logic analyzer). I had this working under the 3.X kernel, but the 4.X kernel has changed to using the dma engine.

CHAR DRIVER CODE FRAGMENTS:

```
struct s_my_ioctl {
    uint32_t    slave_id;   /* Slave ID to assign */
    uint32_t    page_sz;    /* Size of each page */
    uint32_t    src_addr;   /* One source address */
    uint32_t    n_dst;      /* # of destination addresses */
    uint32_t    *pdst_addr; /* Ptr to first designation address */
} sarg; /* Copied with copy_from_user() in an ioctl call */

/* allocate dma (successful)... */
rc = dmaengine_slave_config(dma_chan,&config); /* OK */
...
sglist = kmalloc(sarg.n_dst * sizeof(uint32_t),GFP_KERNEL);
n_sglist = sarg.n_dst;

/* Populate sg_list */
for ( x=0; x<n_sglist; ++x ) {
    sglist[x].page_link = (unsigned long)usr_ptrs[x]; /* ?? */
    sglist[x].offset = 0;
    sglist[x].length = sarg.page_sz;
}

/* Fails */
sgn = dma_map_sg(dma_chan->device->dev,sglist,n_sglist,DMA_DEV_TO_MEM);
```

ABBREV DMESG:

```
(v7_dma_inv_range) from [..] (dma_cache_maint_page+0x84/0x88)         
(dma_cache_maint_page) from [..] (arm_dma_map_page+0x98/0xa4)         
(arm_dma_map_page) from [..] (arm_dma_map_sg+0x88/0xfc)                     
(arm_dma_map_sg) from [..] (rpidma_ioctl+0x348/0x4b0 [rpidma4x])        
(rpidma_ioctl [rpidma4x]) from [..] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x88/0x60c)        
(do_vfs_ioctl) from [..] (SyS_ioctl+0x44/0x68)        
(SyS_ioctl) from [..] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x54)
```

Update (for posterity):

- I was missing a call to sg_init_table(), which has now in place.
- To populate the table, I need to use sg_set_buf() (or sg_set_page()).

So I am getting closer now..